# using for loop to create folders inside every folders in batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I want to get directory `test` which has child directories named `a`, `b`, and `c` each containing three subdirectories, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

e.g.

```
TEST---├-A
       │ ├A
       │ ├B
       │ └C
       ├-B
       │ ├A
       │ ├B
       │ └C
       └-C
         ├A
         ├B
         └C
```

Here's my code:

```bash
@echo off
md test 
cd test
for %%F in (A B C) do (
    md %%F
    cd %%F
    for %%E in (A B C) do (
        md %%E
    )
    cd.
)
pause
```

However, I get this:

```
TEST-A ├-A
       ├-B 
       │ ├-A
       │ ├-B
       │ └-C
       │   ├A
       │   ├B
       │   └C
       └-C
```

I tried using echo like this:

```bash
@echo off
md test 
cd test
for %%F in (A B C) do (
    echo md %%F
    echo cd %%F
    for %%E in (A B C) do (
        echo md %%E
    )
    echo cd.
)
pause
```

result:

```
md A
cd A
md A
md B
md C
cd.
md B
cd B
md A
md B
md C
cd.
md C
cd C
md A
md B
md C
cd.
```

It looks like it works fine..

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just at a glance without running anything, you're `cd`ing into the inner folder, but you aren't `cd`ing back out of it when you're done.

Comment: You can do this in a single line batch file; ```@For %%G In (A B C) Do @For %%H In (A B C) Do @MD test\%%G\%%H```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have a typo at `cd.`: It should be `cd ..`
*(and don't miss the space in between.)*

If you're just learning:

`.` represents the current directory
`..` represents the parent directory.
`cd ..` = "Change into the parent directory"

Here the corrected script:

```
@echo off
md test 
cd test
for %%F in (A B C) do (
    echo md %%F
    echo cd %%F
    for %%E in (A B C) do (
        echo md %%E
    )
    echo cd ..
)
pause
```

Instead  of `pause` you might want to write

```
cd ..
tree test
```

to see the results immediately.